# With Angular module federation v14, how do I prevent a module from loading in both my parent and child apps?

Tags: angular, module, angular14, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm using Angular 14 and module federation.  I have this in my child application

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'childapp',
  exposes: {
    './app1': './src/app/app.module.ts', 
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

In my shell application, I invoke the child using routes like so

```
  {
    path: 'my-child-path',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:8001/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './app1',
      }).then((m) => m.AppModule),
  },
```

However, when I load access the route from the shell application in a browser, I get the JS console error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

In my child app.module.ts file I have

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but if I remove the "BrowserModule" and "BrowserAnimationMoudle" from the child app.module, I get the JS console error

```
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for Compiler!
```

when I attempt to load the child application.  How do I solve this madness?

Comment: is angular version in the child app also 14?

Comment: Yes correct.  For simplicity I'm trying to keep the versions the same.

Answer (score 0):

In child application you should have 2 main modules. 1st - the exposed module `ChildModule` (this one will be exported to the shell), and 2nd one: usually called `AppModule` - basically the module that will be doing "shell" logic for the child application, but the very simple one. This module won't be shipped to the application when opening shell, but it will allow opening standalone child application

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [RootComponent], // component with just <router-outlet>
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./child.module').then((m) => m.ChildModule),
      },
    ]),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Is it possible to export my AppModule, or barring that, the src/main.ts or src/bootstrap.ts file?

Comment: in webpack.config. there is `exposes` section that allows you to export anything you want. for example `exposes: {
    './app1': './src/app/child.module.ts', 
  },
`